# Synchronizing Animation with bpm in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, synchronization

I created a **Metronome** script calculating beat interval using bpm variable from MusicController script. When beat advances I set the trigger for animation to switch to another sprite of metronomeUI.

What I found out is that metronome animation has a small delay and I have no idea how I could reduce the delay for it so it matches with the music. Any ideas on how I could fix it?

Besides that I also have method *IsOnBeat()* that returns true in a small beatWindow after beat is changed. I use that method in **EnvironmentBeat** class that for now controls scale of objects to "Dance" to the beat. I found out that its a bit buggy, objects in facts scale to the beat but from time to time they glitch out and you can see them scaling 2-3 times while *IsOnBeat* is true.

**Metronome class:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Metronome : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Metronome Settings")] 
    public float bpm;
    public float beatWindow = 0.2f;
    public float delayStart;
    
    private float _beatInterval;
    private float _timer;
    private int _currentBeat = 1;
    private float _lastBeatTime;
    private bool _canStart;
    
    [Header("References")]
    public AudioSource audioSource;
    public MusicController musicController;
    
    private Animator _animator;

    private void Start()
    {
        _canStart = false;
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        StartCoroutine(CheckBpm(delayStart / 3));
        StartCoroutine(DelayStart(delayStart));
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (_canStart)
        {
            _timer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (_timer >= _beatInterval)
            {
                _timer -= _beatInterval;
                AdvanceBeat();
            }
        }
    }

    private void AdvanceBeat()
    {
        _animator.SetTrigger("NextBeat");
        audioSource.Play();

        _currentBeat++;
        if (_currentBeat > 4)
        {
            _currentBeat = 1;
        }

        _lastBeatTime = Time.time;
    }

    private void CalculateBeatInterval()
    {
        _beatInterval = 60f / bpm;
    }

    public void SetBpm(int newBpm)
    {
        bpm = newBpm;
        CalculateBeatInterval();
    }

    public int GetCurrentBeat()
    {
        return _currentBeat;
    }

    public bool IsOnBeat()
    {
        float timeSinceLastBeat = Time.time - _lastBeatTime;
        return timeSinceLastBeat <= beatWindow;
    }

    public int BeatMultiplier()
    {
        switch (_currentBeat)
        {
            case 1:
                return 5;
            case 2:
                return 2;
            case 3:
                return 5;
            case 4:
                return 2;
        }

        return 2;
    }

    private IEnumerator DelayStart(float delay)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        _canStart = true;
        _timer = 0;
        musicController.audioSourceA.Play();
        
    }

    private IEnumerator CheckBpm(float delay)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        bpm = musicController.currentTrack.bpm;
        CalculateBeatInterval();
    }
}
```

**EnvironmentBeat class:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnvironmentBeat : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Settings")] 
    public bool isScaling;
    public bool isJumping;

    [Header("References")] 
    public Metronome metronome;

    private Vector3 _originalScale;

    private void Start()
    {
        _originalScale = transform.localScale;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (metronome.IsOnBeat())
        {
            if (isScaling)
            {
                BeatScaling();
            }
        }

        if (isJumping)
        {
            Debug.Log("Not Implemented");
        }
    }


    private void BeatScaling()
    {
        float scaleMultiplier = 1.2f;
        transform.localScale = _originalScale * scaleMultiplier;

        StartCoroutine(ResetScaleAfterDelay(0.1f));
    }

    private IEnumerator ResetScaleAfterDelay(float delay)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        transform.localScale = _originalScale;
    }
}
```

I was thinking of measuring the delay and applying it to either starting the audioClip or metronome animation but Im not sure if the current delay is hardware specific and I can imagine that on slower/faster pc it might be different.

Answer (score 0):

try using FixedUpdate rather than Update maybe.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html

Comment: I tried using FixedUpdate but unfortunately it didn't seem to resolve that problem.

Comment: @Pnukso hmm, not too sure then but you might have some luck using Time.DeltaTime which gives you the time since the last frame, this could be the delay https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html